# MVC.Net Action link to update partial

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm using partial views within an MVC.Net website to display content from a database.
I want to be able to offer as WYSIWYG as possible an interface for modifying that content.

Ideally I'd like to be able to put an `@Html.Action` in whatever page I need some content on. Then automatically offer an "*Edit*" link for authenticated users.

Once the edit link is clicked, I want to show the same page as they were already on. (From a different controller). But with the partial replaced with it's "*Edit*" state alternative.

Obviously at the moment, putting an `ActionLink` in the partial navigates away from the current page and displays the Edit view full screen.

The Controller "SiteCMSController" looks up the id from the db/cache and inserts it in the page.
If the user is an admin, it adds an edit link.

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("_Content", "SiteCMS", new { id = 1 })
</div>
```

results in

```
<div>
    Some text pulled in from the database.
    <br>
    <a href="~/SiteCMS/Edit/1">Edit this content</a>
</div>
```

(Off the top of my head code.)

Comment: jQuery `.load()` - http://api.jquery.com/load/. If you post some code for what you're doing so far I will post an answer showing how to integrate `.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

use some ajax

```
<div>
    @Ajax.Actionlink("_Content", "SiteCMS", new { id = 1}, new AjaxOptions {       UpdateTargetId = "someDiv"})
</div>
```

UpdateTargetId, this is were your partial will be stored, you have to make a div with the id "someDiv", or something else ofc :)

Comment: This should work, although the built-in Ajax handling tends to be so cumbersome/rudimentary I almost always end up using jQuery more directly.